# YAML File has a syntax error, but it looks like it has the same format as another one that is working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I have two YAML files with similar formats, however one is running and the other is not running when I run integration tests on my rails app.

Here is the first YAML file which doesn't work:

```
prince_edward_island:
  name: 'prince edward island'
  country: 'Canada'
```

nova_scotia:
      name: 'nova scotia'
      country: 'Canada'

```
newfoundland:
  name: 'newfoundland'
  country: 'Canada'

new_brunswick:
  name: 'new brunswick'
  country: 'Canada'

quebec:
  name: 'quebec'
  country: 'Canada'

manitoba:
  name: 'manitoba'
  country: 'Canada'

alberta:
  name: 'alberta'
  country: 'Canada'

ontario:
  name: 'ontario'
  country: 'Canada'

british_columbia: 'Canada'
  name: 'british columbia'
  country: 'Canada'

saskatchewan: 'Canada'
  name: 'saskatchewan'
  country: 'Canada'
```

Here is the second YAML file which does work:

```
student_advisor_message:
  body: 'This is a message'
  subject: 'Subject!'
  user: student_advisor

manager_message:
  body: 'This is a message'
  subject: 'Subject!'
  user: manager

read_manager_message:
  body: 'This is a message'
  subject: 'Subject!'
  user: manager

agent_manager_message:
  body: 'This is a message'
  subject: 'Subject!'
  user: agent_manager

message_for_jack:
  body: 'This is a message'
  subject: 'Subject!'
  user: manager

message_for_jack_sent:
  body: 'This is a sent message'
  subject: 'Sent Subject!'
  user: manager

message_for_jack_trash:
  body: 'This is a trashed message'
  subject: 'Trash Subject!'
  user: manager
```

The error is:

```
ERROR:

while parsing a block mapping
  in "<unicode string>", line 1, column 1:
    prince_edward_island:
    ^
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
  in "<unicode string>", line 34, column 3:
      name: 'british columbia'
```

Can someone explain the difference I am missing between the two? For both I use spaces, not tabs.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors:

> For both I use tabs, not spaces.

Tabs are not allowed as indentation characters in YAML.

```
country: 'Canada'

  nova_scotia:
```

Here, you give both a scalar (`'Canada'`) and a mapping (starting with `nova_scotia:`) as value for the key `country`. There may only be one value for this key. You either have to remove the scalar `'Canada'` or move the mapping it contains elsewhere.

```
british_columbia: 'Canada'
  name: 'british columbia'
  country: 'Canada'

saskatchewan: 'Canada'
  name: 'saskatchewan'
  country: 'Canada'
```

Here, you make the same error again twice.

Comment: For the first, I meant spaces, not tabs** I apologize. For the second, the second half of my code was accidentally re-tabbed. As for the third, I believe that is where the error lies, thank you. Amit also had the correct answer, but as this is more thorough for the unedited question, I'll accept this one.

Answer (score 0):

A parent in the yaml file cannot have a value.

when you remove(or comment) `Canada` from these lines, it will parse properly.

```
british_columbia: 'Canada'
  name: 'british columbia'
  country: 'Canada'

saskatchewan: #'Canada'
  name: 'saskatchewan'
  country: 'Canada'
```